# How to limit the dependencies downloaded by Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Has Maven some security parameter to limit the number or depth of dependencies downloaded to the local repository when building a pom?

Imagine an artifacts repository *hacked* in a way that, for every artifact `dummy-1.0` requested, it serves dinamically a `dummy-1.0` which has a dependency on `dummy-1.1`, and so on.

Has Maven some security mechanism to avoid such an infinite loop?

(I haven't found it explicitly on Maven's documentation nor googling it).

Comment: First misunderstanding is the a release artifact in your case `dummy-1.0` will be requested exactly once...after that it will be cached in the local cache ($HOME/.m2/repository) furthermore you should check if you have warnings based on the checksum...apart from that you should your https to transfer artifacts ...and not to forget always use a repository manager in your local network...

Comment: No misunderstanding: What I mean is that, theoretically, it is possible to have an **infinite** dependency chain: dummy-1.0 -> dummy-1.1 -> dummy-1.2 -> dummy-1.3 ... No matter if each one of these artifacts gets chached in the local cahe, for it depends on another artifact more.

Comment: To be clear: theoretically many things are possible...That means you need to hack either an existing repository or you offer a new one which you need to persuade someone to use it...Apart from build time changes etc. Finally there is no such parameter in Maven and would not make sense...cause where would you limit the deepth? 3, 5, 10, 20 ? I have seen many dep trees which have a very great deepth...

Comment: I think it would make sense: Almost all systems I've seen have **physical security limits** to avoid an accidental (or intentional) overflow: The amount of heap memory of the JVM, the size of a string field in a relational schema, etc. That is my question about.